# opendir warning acces denied, shows two params instead of one

Tags: php, opendir

i have just silly question. When i have this code in PHP

```
$dirResult = opendir($pathReal);
```

where path real is string contains path to file, i get error

*Warning: opendir(\149.223.22.11\cae\04_Knowledge-base,\149.223.22.11\cae\04_Knowledge-base): Access is denied.*

I know, that issue is with user rights in path im trying to acces, thats clear. But what concerns me is why in warning is opendir parameter written twice?

I would expect warning like this

*Warning: opendir(\149.223.22.11\cae\04_Knowledge-base): Access is denied.*

but nop. Also i double checked input value, and it seems correct to me. Normal string value with only one path parameter.

edit:

Also when i take a look at next warning
*Warning: opendir(\149.223.22.11\cae\04_Knowledge-base): failed to open dir:*

there is opendir param only one, what seems correct to me :)

Comment: if there is permission issue. give permission chmod -R 777 [file]

Comment: yeah, i what issue is, but im curious about warning message. I will try to edit question to be more transparent

Comment: Warnings are not important. if you got answer from my prev comment then i am putting it in answer.

Comment: Probably just a faulty generation of the warning message by PHP …

Comment: check permissions by `int fileperms ( string $filename )` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php